# How to Embed Fonts in Action script 3

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to get a specific Font family into my application, but i am unsure on how to embed my fonts properly?

I did follow this [tutorial](http://www.guahanweb.com/2009/05/07/embedding-fonts-into-actionscript-only-project-as3/)

but I am getting error at this line:

```
[Embed(source="C:\\WINDOWS\\Fonts\\Bebas_Neue_Regular.OTF", fontFamily="Bebas_Neue")]
```

The error is :

```
Scene 1, Layer 'Code', Frame 3, Line 2  An Embed variable must not have an existing value.
```

This app is for Air Ios. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That is for the flex compiler.  Your using flashPro, so you do it in the library.  If you have a text field instance on the timeline, there will be an embed button on the properties panel.

Comment: umm, So i just directly go to the format step?

Comment: This is how you do it with code:  http://www.gaslightgames.co.uk/?p=163.  I don't have flashPro on the computer I'm using at the moment, but if no one has answered by tomorrow I'll post some screenshots of what buttons you need to hit.   Basically though, you just select a textfield, go to the properties panel, select the embed option, and choose which characters to embed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Programmatically in code, when linking to a font file or system font I follow the pattern:

```
/**
 * U+0020-U+002F,  Space + Punctuation [ !"#$%&amp;'()*+,-./ ]
 * U+0030-U+0039,  Numbers [0..9]
 * U+003A-U+0040,  Special Chars [ :;&lt;=&gt;?@ ]
 * U+0041-U+005A,  Upper-Case [A..Z]
 * U+005B-U+0060,  Special Chars [ [\]^_` ]
 * U+0061-U+007A,  Lower-Case a-z
 * U+007B-U+007E,  Special Chars [ {|}~ ]
 * U+00A1-U+00A1,  Latin Character: ¡
 * U+00A3-U+00A3,  British Pound Symbol
 * U+00A9-U+00A9,  Copyright Symbol
 * U+00AE-U+00AE,  Registered Symbol
 * U+00B0-U+00B0,  Degrees Symbol
 * U+00BC-U+00BE,  Fractions Symbols
 * U+00BF-U+00BF,  Latin Character: ¿
 * U+00C0-U+00FF,  Latin Characters
 * U+2013-U+2014,  EN Dash, EM Dash
 * U+2018-U+2019,  Directional Single Quotes
 * U+201C-U+201D,  Directional Double Quotes
 * U+2022-U+2023,  Bullets
 * U+2120-U+2120,  SM
 * U+2122-U+2122   Trade mark (TM)
 */
[Embed(systemFont = "Arial", fontWeight = "Regular", fontName = "Arial", mimeType = "application/x-font", embedAsCFF = "false", unicodeRange = "U+0020-U+002F,U+0030-U+0039,U+003A-U+0040,U+0041-U+005A,U+005B-U+0060,U+0061-U+007A,U+007B-U+007E,U+00A1-U+00A1,U+00A3-U+00A3,U+00A9-U+00A9,U+00AE-U+00AE,U+00B0-U+00B0,U+00BC-U+00BE,U+00BF-U+00BF,U+00C0-U+00FF,U+2013-U+2014,U+2018-U+2019,U+201C-U+201D,U+2022-U+2023,U+2120-U+2120,U+2122-U+2122")]
private static const ArialClass:Class;
```

Then, a TextFormat may be created as:

```
Font.registerFont(ArialClass);

var tf:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
tf.font = "Arial";
tf.bold = bold;
tf.size = size;
tf.color = color;
tf.align = TextFormatAlign.LEFT;
```

With Flash Pro, fonts can be dragged and dropped on the library, or right-click and select *New Font...*

[image: new-font]

Properties may be set from the *Font Embedding* window:

[image: font-embedding]

Flash Pro's GUI makes font embedding easy, and fonts can be published as a SWC for linkage to other projects outside of the Flash Pro authoring environment.